# How to search a vector of structs for a matching string and return the integer value associated with that string in the vector of structs?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

C++ beginner here working on my first original project, so bear with me here if something seems obvious to you.

I have created a vector of structs to house 2 pieces of information, playerName and playerValue. I also have a vector of strings of names. I am trying to find if a specific element in my names vector exists in the vector of structs, and if so, return the associated playerValue. However I am struggling to do so.

```
struct playerData
{
    std::string playerName;
    int playerValue;
};
```

Here is how I am creating the vector of playerData and adding elements to it

```
std::vector<playerData> populateList()
{
    std::vector<playerData> totalPlayerVector;
    totalPlayerVector.push_back(playerData());
    totalPlayerVector[0].playerName = "Julio Jones";
    totalPlayerVector[0].playerValue = 18;

    totalPlayerVector.push_back(playerData());
    totalPlayerVector[1].playerName = "Saquon Barkley";
    totalPlayerVector[1].playerValue = 25;
    return totalPlayerVector;
}
```

Then I am trying to determine if a name that is within a vector can also be found within totalPlayerVector, and if so, return its associated playerValue. Here the issues begin.

```
std::vector<std::string> vecPlayersTraded{};
```

```
for (int i{ 0 }; i < numOfPlayerTraded; ++i)
    {
        if (std::find(totalPlayerVector.begin(), totalPlayerVector.end(), vecPlayersTraded[i]) != totalPlayerVector.end())
        {
            x += totalPlayerVector[i].playerValue;
        }
    {
```

Here is my overloaded operator. How do I iterate over playerVec[i] and compare it to all possible values of playerData[x].playerName? playerData is much larger than playerVec

```
bool operator!=(std::vector<std::string> playerVec, std::vector<playerData> fullData)
{
    int size{ static_cast<int>(sizeof(playerVec)) - 1 };
    int size2{ static_cast<int>(sizeof(playerData)) - 1 };
    for (int i{0}; i < size; ++i)
    {
    return !(playerVec[i] == (for (int j{0}; j < size; ++j){ fullData[j].playerName};
    }
```

So my first issue is that it won't compile, my compiler tells me operator == cannot take lefthand operand playerData. Moreover, even if it would compile, it wouldn't work correctly because my overloaded operator is not implemented correctly.

How do I properly search through a vector of structs to find if a string matches one of the struct elements? And if it matches, retrieve the other value stored in the struct?

Secondly, how do I properly overload the != operator so I can compare a string to a string that is an element of a struct that is an element of a vector?

Comment: Try [find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

Comment: Good question shall concentrate on one problem... Let's assume that you have proper == operator --- then std::find will return an iterator pointing to matching element. Note that it may be first, second or hunderth and you are actually not interested which number it is. And for sure, it is not related to ```i``` anyhow. So look at what iterator is and how to use it.